# Take high quality screenshots of my terminal window

Tags: terminal, screenshot

I'm writing a book and sometimes I must show some screenshots taken from my terminal window. Problem is they are not good for print, so I need to increase their quality (resolution). Is there any way to take screenshots at a higher resolution? At the moment, I'm using Ubuntu (is there any way to simulate HIdpi and take the screenshot?).

Comment: Just increase the font size?

Comment: Interesting, but they asked me 300 dpi images. I even thought I could use my camera, but...

Comment: You can also scale the image using GIMP

Comment: It's a raster image, not a vector...

Comment: copy\paste the text then just use a monospace font with black\green colors - no longer dealing with pictures, and digital versions people can copy commands...

Comment: Since it's 300ppi, I'd suggest asking them what the targeted font size is in mm or inches and then simply copy/paste the scaled text from a renderd output, or simply typeset it with TeX. If you need the actual terminal emulator window to be rendered as well (windows frame, etc), consider faking it. Make a close representation in Inkscape and then just use a vector image.

Comment: Mateo, problem is the publisher uses its own style and I can't change it   ;-)   "Its own style" means he likes image

Comment: polemon, it's ok, but faking dozen of windows can be a little "tricky"...   :-)

Answer (score 4):

The best way to get print-quality output from what is actually text is to actually represent it as text, rather than as a picture. If you take an actual screenshot of the terminal emulator window, then by definition of a screenshot, you'll get a screen-resolution bitmap.

You can use the [`script`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html) command to make a record of everything that's output to the terminal. A nice thing about using `script` is that it doesn't require any cooperation from the application or from the terminal. However it does have: a downside: the resulting transcript includes the escape sequences sent by the application as-is, including cursor motion, overwrites, etc. so in the general case you need to essentially write a terminal emulator to parse its output.

You can run the application in screen, and use its `hardcopy` command (`C-a h`). This produces a file (called `hardcopy.0` by default) that contains the content of the screen. This does not contain any markup (bold, color, etc.).

Xterm has a print feature, which you can invoke from the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Mouse1</kbd> (Ctrl+left-click) menu. By default, this only prints the text, but you can tell Xterm to include escape sequences for video attributes:

```
xterm -xrm '*printerCommand: cat' -xrm '*printModeImmediate: 2'
```

You can add a menu entry or keyboard shortcut to the `print` function with `colorAttr=2` to get this effect. By default, the currently visible screen and the saved lines are included; this can be controlled via the `printOptsImmediate` resource or via arguments to the `print` function. For example, to only get the visible part, you can use

```
xterm -xrm '*printerCommand: cat' -xrm '*printModeImmediate: 2' -xrm '*printOptsImmediate: 1'
```

The output is in a file called `XTerm` followed by a timestamp (you can change the prefix with the `printFileImmediate` resource). This contains ANSI escape sequences to change text attributes, which you can convert to whatever format you use to typeset your book (e.g. [via HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245121/a-library-to-convert-ansi-escapes-terminal-formatting-color-codes-to-html)).

A perhaps more convenient approach would be to use Emacs as the terminal emulator. Install a print-to-PDF-file printer ([cups-pdf](http://www.cups-pdf.de/), should be available in your distribution). Set it as the [default printer](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Printing.html) in Emacs (use the configuration interface or put `(setq printer-name "pdf")` in your `.emacs`). Run `M-x term` to get a terminal emulator, and select “File” → “Postscript Print Buffer” in the menu to print. (Don't use the plain “Print Buffer”, that would produce a low-quality bitmap.)

Comment: Very interesting, I'll give it a try   :-)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the program shutter.  I use it all the time for taking screen shots of terminals / etc.  Resolution seems very good to me.  You can even turn it up if needed.

Comment: shutter is great, but it just uses the native resolution of what you are seeing. How could you "turn it up"?

Comment: @Sparhawk Depends on which image format you are using under preferences. JPG has a quality setting you can increase for example.   I should have said, the image format and compression methods can be changed to increase quality depending on the current settings.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. I normally capture in something lossless like png. I suspect the question was more about increasing the resolution of captures, or even better (as per the other answer) representing the text as text, or a vector format.

Comment: Exactly, it's not a format problem, it's a resolution one